# How to replace tab's indent by space's indent with web-mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, html, indentation

I don't want to use tabs for indent, so I add `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` in my emacs init file.

With the setting indents are created by spaces in `web-mode`, but it doesn't change already existing tabs to spaces.

Is there a config like `overwrite-tab-indent-by-space-indent`?
Or must I replace tabs to spaces by command every time I encounter tab-indented HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question--is running `M-x untabify` after selecting the whole buffer acceptable, or are you seeking an automated solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To untabify the whole buffer upon opening a file that uses web-mode, you could add something like this to your init file:

```
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook
  (lambda () (untabify (point-min) (point-max))))
```

This assumes that `web-mode` is the name of the mode you want this setting to apply to; adjust to taste.

Comment: I didn't know the `untabify`, thanks!